# Google Sitemap Non-Specific Error

Tags: xml, sitemap

Google's Webmaster Tools gives me the following status about my sitemap, but there is no specific error. The XML seems to be valid. Any ideas?

```
URLs in Sitemap: Total: 7, Indexed: 6  
Submitted: Feb 14, 2010 – Error 
Downloaded: Feb 14, 2010

Sitemap errors and warnings

Line: - 
Status: We encountered an error while trying to access your Sitemap. Please ensure your Sitemap follows our guidelines and can be accessed at the location you provided and then resubmit.   
Details: Problem detected on: Feb 14, 2010
```

Actual sitemap: http://www.beechtreetech.com/google-site-map.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server claims the file contains `text/html`, which it doesn't. Google is probably expecting `application/xml`.